# exp:channel:entries not working by any means

Tags: templates

I cannot get any queries to work using exp:channel:entries.

```
{exp:channel:entries orderby="date" start_on="2015-07-01 20:00" channel="shipments" limit="10" dynamic="no"}
<p>inloop</p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Here is my query above. I have tried every combination of its option variables and nothing works. I cannot get any query to work for any channels except the one below,

```
{exp:channel:entries}
<p>inloop<p>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Which is just pulling out 100 entries.

This is a old site for a client that uses expressionengine only as a backend solution. Its V2.6.1 There are no other templates. I am not using file templates, only database. Is there some setting that restricts channels from being used in templates that I am unaware of?

Comment: You may find that the start_on parameter was not available in that version (I don't have the docs back that far). There is nothing that would prevent a channel tag from running in a template. That's what they were design for. Start with your loop that works and add parameters until it doesn't. Also try setting the show_future_entries parameter.

Comment: I have stripped away everything except for and when doing channel is when it breaks. Super weird. Just cannel. And dynamic. So this does not work,                                                                                    {exp:channel:entries channel="shipments" dynamic="no"}
<p>inloop<p>
{/exp:channel:entries}

Comment: Actually it just seems to be breaking on 1 channel. Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

The channel ended up having custom status types so the defaults were not working. I did not make this website so I did not realize this was the case.